# C - Scan chars and show ASCII code

Tags: c, string, char

This is  a super basic question... I am relearning C (haven't used it for more than 5 years). I can't get this code to work. I am trying to scan a user input (ascii character) as an integer, and show the ascii code for the entered character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int character;

  printf("Welcome to ASCII:\n");

  do {
    scanf("%d",&character);

    printf("ascii: %d\n",character);
  } while(character != 999);

  printf("Done.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

It just shows 0 for every input...

Comment: works for me.  Use fgets(buffer,size,stream), and sscanf() to pull input, then invalid input doesn't mess you up.  Anyway, what character(s) are you entering?  because if you are trying to enter a character and convert it to ordinal value, use "%c" for scanf() and char character[99] for input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*" I am trying to scan a user input (ascii character) as an integer, and show the ascii code for the entered character"*

What you should do is exact opposite. You should read a character and display it as an integer, i.e.:

```
char c;
scanf("%c", &c);    // <-- read character
printf("%d", c);    // <-- display its integral value
```

input: `a`, output: `97`

---

Also note that `while(character != 999)` isn't very lucky choice for a terminating condition of your loop. Checking the return value of `scanf` to determine whether the reading of character was successful might be more reasonable here:

```
while (scanf("%c", &character)) {
    printf("ascii: %d\n", character);
}
```

Comment: yes but his code will go into a infinite loop .. as he is not compensating for the enter pressed after input

Comment: Thank you! About 999 : I initially had `!= 0` (that's the termination code) but switched to 999 because I was getting 0 for the user input.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char character;

  printf("Welcome to ASCII:\n");

  do {
    scanf("%c",&character);
    getchar(); // to get rid of enter after input

    printf("ascii: %d\n",character);
  } while(character != 999);

  printf("Done.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
d
ascii: 100
s
ascii: 115
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read an integer(scanf("%d", &...)) and it's normal this operation to fail and the value to be 0 - a default value for int variable. Change the "%d" to "%c" and it should work.

Comment: I'm very suspicious of "a default value for int variable". C doesn't work like that. If the extraction fails, you mustn't read the variable. It doesn't have a deterministic value, and it may be UB to read it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, just a friendly heads up, you can use backticks instead of quotes for inline code

Answer (score 0):

change to :

```
printf("ascii: %c\n",character);
```

However , What your condition speciftied `999`?